# How to display only one row from foreach array?

Tags: php, mysql

I have following code:

```
if (!$wsql->query('SELECT href FROM a ')){
    print "Query error: " . $wsql->error; 
    exit;
}

foreach($wsql->fetch_array() as $row){

    //dump all
    var_dump($row);

}
```

I can dump content of whole array

```
array (size=1)
'href' => string 'teststring' (length=10)
```

but how i can get only one record from it?

something like this:

```
 foreach($wsql->fetch_array() as $row){

   echo $row[0];  

}
```

Doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of the foreach use

```
$row = $wsql->fetch_array();
echo $row;
```

Comment: if it worked - accept the answer - The tick on the left hand side

Answer (score 1):

Try with `exit` like

```
foreach($wsql->fetch_array() as $row){
    print_r($row);
    exit;   
}
```

You can also use `break`

```
foreach($wsql->fetch_array() as $row){
    print_r($row);
    break;   
}
```

Or simply give `LIMIT` value to `1` ,then you dont need to fetch all the data.It will reduce the DB load also

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$row = $wsql->fetch_array();
echo $row;
```

Comment: missing the ";" at the end

Answer (score 0):

`fetch_array()` fetches *one* record in an array. To get one record just use that.

```
$record_as_array = $wsql->fetch_array();
```